# How to add rows up to point?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have pandas series. I would like to add the rows to be equal to value.
For example, I would like to add the first few values to be equal to `0.19798863694528301`.
Then add from the beginning so that the second value will be equal to `3.79478220811793`, and so forth.

That data is given below:

```
0.0
0.015
0.03
0.045
0.06
0.075
0.09
0.105
0.12
0.135
0.15
0.165
0.18
0.195
0.21
0.225
0.24
0.255
0.27
0.285
0.3
0.315
0.33
0.345
0.36
0.375
0.39
0.405
0.42
0.435
0.45
0.465
0.48
0.495
0.51
0.525
0.54
0.555
0.57
0.585
0.6
0.615
0.63
0.645
0.66
0.675
0.69
0.705
0.72
0.735
0.75
0.765
0.78
0.795
0.81
0.825
```

Comment: In the data you've given, you have the multiplicands of 0.15. Am I right? Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Better show in question expected result.